# Separate Ethernet card from Network Manager's management

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have Network Manager on my 14.04 laptop.  It currently manages the networking.

Unfortunately, I don't want Network Manager to manage the Ethernet card, `eth0`, and I just want it to handle the wireless `wlan0` card.

I'd like to let the system (`dhclient`, etc.) handle my Ethernet, not Network Manager.

Is it as simple as turning the `eth0` interface over to the kernel via `/etc/network/interfaces` and adding an `eth0` stanza, or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: If you add eth0 to /etc/network/interfaces, NM will stop managing this interface.

Comment: @Pilot6 add that as an answer please?  (I ask whether it's that simple or not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network Manager does not manage interfaces that are mentioned in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

That sometimes confuse people. If you add all interfaces there, NM indicator will not appear at all.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wasn't sure.  Thanks for your answer!